# Product review "Submit" button not working

Tags: product, review

I installed Yotpo reviews extension and disabled the Magento's default review block from `Configuration> Advanced> Disable Modules Output> Mage_Reviews`.

Soon after installing it I found a free extension that could help in generating Google Rich Snippets, so I installed it and and installed the other block. I also Enabled the Mage_Reviews block from both the views in `Configuration> Current Configuration Scope`. Both means from default as well as from Website view.

Later I found that the reviews form button is not working. I mean there is no problem with the form but the Submit button isn't working. Clicking on it does nothing! It's like an empty button with no function command. May I know what is the issue? Can anyone please help me in solving this?

Here is the Code that I'm getting after using "Inspect element" feature in Chrome.

[image: Javascript code]

Comment: There is likely a javascript error. Can you check the javascript console and paste your exact error here in an edit to your question?

Comment: I don't know which file I should check because my knowledge in coding is NIL. Could you please lemme know what exactly should I see to find the error and paste it here?

Comment: @MohitSingh See https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console

Comment: @R.S- Done. Please have a look

Answer (score -3, accepted):

It's working fine now. It was a problem related to a block.

Comment: Could you specify this? I'm running into the same issue now after upgrading Magento 1.7.0.1 to 1.9.2.4